# One page checkout : ajax error

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I using one page checkout plugin on magento 1.9.4.
https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout-m1.html

On checkout page, when i change payment method I get below error,

```
Not connect. Verify Network. Ajax error.
```

Can You help me? How i can fix it?

Thank

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with the payment provider, whichever you are using, or a compatibility issues between both. Unfortunately bugs with 3rd party extensions are considered off topic here, you should try to get help from their support.

Comment: One page checkout is the most used plugin for the checkout. I thick this topic can be interest for all

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we need to understand if this error is caused by OnestepCheckout module OR Payment method that you've selected.

1) If you have Code access and can edit it. 
You need to find this text in your code - "Not connect. Verify Network. Ajax error." 
I think it will look like

```
catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError('Not connect. Verify Network. Ajax error.');
            }
```

and you need to modify it to

```
catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError('Not connect. Verify Network. Ajax error.' . $e->getMessage());
            }
```

Then you will have more detailed message explaining error.

2) If you have no code access.

Go to Admin - System - Configuration - Developer  and enable Logging there.
Clean all caches after that.
Then go to checkout and repeat error.
Then you need to check var/log folder of your magento instance and can find more detailed explanation of issue there. But maybe this custom module can prevent any logging of errors, related to this error message.

Comment: Not so easy. There is many file. In log there is not message.